# Why does this C code cause segmentation error? Trying to understand pointers

Tags: c

Trying to understand what exactly happens in the memory during the execution of this code and why it causes a segmentation error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int* ptr;
    *ptr = 5;
    printf("%d", *ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `*ptr = 5` attempts to write `5` to the address held in `p`. Questions: what _is_ this address? Do you have permission to write to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All variables must first be initialized to a valid value before you can use them in an expression like `*p`. For pointers, this means assigning an address to point to. You can do this either by taking the address of another variable or by dynamically allocating memory with `malloc()`.

When you try to dereference an uninitialized pointer with `*p`, it will use whatever memory address happens to be stored in `p` at that time. Most likely this address is invalid for you to use and so you get a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

First allocate memory to the pointer variable

```
ptr = (int* ) malloc(sizeof(int))
```

Comment: The OP was asking why a seg fault was happening. This will fix the seg fault, but doesn't really explain what's going on in the original bit of code.

Comment: Please change it as     ptr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));

Comment: @Mani You can edit your answer yourself.

Comment: @Mani Why do you want `(int*)`? It's completely unnecessary. Also, you could change `sizeof(int)` to `sizeof(*ptr)`.